# Google Sheets Pivot Table: MIN and MAX within a group

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have the following source data in Google sheets

| Date | Place of Stay |
| --- | --- |
| 1-Sep | Miami |
| 2-Sep | Miami |
| 3-Sep | Miami |
| 4-Sep | Marathon |
| 5-Sep | Key West |
| 6-Sep | Key West |
| 7-Sep | Miami |
| 8-Sep | N/A |

Using this, I've constructed the following pivot table:

| Place of Stay | Check-in | Check-out |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Miami | 1-Sep | 8-Sep |
| Marathon | 4-Sep | 5-Sep |
| Key West | 5-Sep | 7-Sep |

For the "Check-in" field, I simply took a MIN of the Date field. The "Check-out" is a "calculated field" which does a =MAX('Date')+1.

However, this is not the desired pivot table output that I want to see, because this looks like I'm checking into Miami on 9/1 and only checking out on 9/8 where in reality, I'm checking into Miami again on 9/7 and checking out on 9/8.

So the ideal output I'd like to see is

| Place of Stay | Check-in | Check-out |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Miami | 1-Sep | 4-Sep |
| Marathon | 4-Sep | 5-Sep |
| Key West | 5-Sep | 7-Sep |
| Miami | 7-Sep | 8-Sep |

So every time the place of stay changes, I need a new entry in the pivot table which indicates a check-in and checkout.

Any idea how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a group with such a formula (it is possible to find an arrayformula)

```
=if(B2=B1,C1,C1+1)
```

and then perform a pivot table. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P_NlIf4r4LlXuj8FDn-AcSlUYSK6hwqbOoyrq-0KU5E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mike. This does the trick. Extra thanks for actually sharing the demo sheet!